# How can I treat data differently with radioButtons in Shiny?

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, radio-button

I am trying to create an app with Shiny and I would like to treat differently the data from each radio button to create different plots for each of the radioButton options.

The code that I have and works is this one:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(wakefield)

#Create dummy dataset named datos
X <- r_sample_factor(c("low", "high"), n=232)
MAMAMA<-r_sample_factor(c("C/C", "C/G", "G/G"), n=232)
MEMEME<-r_sample_factor(c("C/C", "C/T", "T/T"), n=232)
MIMIMI<-r_sample_factor(c("A/A", "A/T", "T/T"), n=232)
datos<-data.frame(X,MAMAMA,MEMEME,MIMIMI)

#Data partition
set.seed(12345)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=datos$X, p=0.66666666666666667, list=FALSE)
datos_train<-datos[inTrain,]
datos_test<-datos[-inTrain,]
class_train<-datos[inTrain,1]
class_test<-datos[-inTrain,1]

#Define ui

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("This is a title"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons("algorithm",
                         "Select one algorithm to visualize its output",
                         choices= c("Random Forest" = "rf",
                                    "Artificial Neural Network" = "mlp",
                                    "Support Vector Machine" = "svmRadial") )

        ),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                        tabPanel("Prediction", verbatimTextOutput("confucio")),
                        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
                        tabPanel("Confussion Matrix", verbatimTextOutput("matrix"))
                        )
            #From select variable model
            #tableOutput("table"),
            #plotOutput("myPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$confucio<-renderPrint(train(X~., datos_train, 
                                       method=input$algorithm,
                                       trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5)))

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot(train(X~., datos_train, method=input$algorithm, trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5)))
        })


    output$matrix<-renderPrint({ confusionMatrix(
        predict(
            train(X~., datos_train, method=input$algorithm, trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5)), datos_test)
        , class_test)
    })
    }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, for output$plot I would like to do different plots for each of the radiobutton possibilities. I tried this but it does not work.

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
        if(input$algorithm == "Random Forest"){
            model<-train(X~., datos_train, method="rf", trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5))
            plot(model$finalModel, main="Random Forest") 
            } 
        if(input$algorithm == "Artificial Neural Network"){
            model<-train(X~., datos_train, method="mlp", trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5))
            plotnet(model, main="Artificial Neural Network")
            }
        if(input$algorithm == "Support Vector Machine"){
            model<-train(X~., datos_train, method="svmRadial", trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5))
            plot(model, main="Support Vector Machine")
            } 

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "raw" names that are in `radioButtons` in the `if` conditions, not the new names you give to the choices:

```
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$algorithm == "rf"){
      model<-train(X~., datos_train, method="rf", trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5))
      plot(model$finalModel, main="Random Forest") 
    } 
    if(input$algorithm == "mlp"){
      model<-train(X~., datos_train, method="mlp", trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5))
      plotnet(model, main="Artificial Neural Network")
    }
    if(input$algorithm == "svmRadial"){
      model<-train(X~., datos_train, method="svmRadial", trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5))
      plot(model, main="Support Vector Machine")
    } 

  })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought this was the first thing I tried and didn't work, but I may had the code wrong then